# Expanding the disk size on pfsense under VMWare ESXi

Tags: freebsd, vmware, disk, pfsense

I've been testing **pfsense** on **ESXi** for a while. And now I'm almost running out of space. Currently it holds around **30GB** and I would like to expand it to **150GB** as I'm planning on installing squid for caching. So far what I did is;

- Tried to expand the disk on ESXi for pfsense (its a thick provisioned drive) which expanded and showing as free.
- Tried gparted by booting and iso into the pfsense VM which showed that the installed partition is an unknown one & the unallocated didn't even show options to resize (guess it is because pfsense uses UFS file system)
- Tried installing a fresh copy which was successful but the UI was pretty strange as I couldn't see the total usage, memory usage.. etc.. not even the status bars properly.

My pfsense is making a lot of trouble. All I need is to expand the disk on the old pfsense if possible else a fix for the new one (where the GUI looks pretty sluggish).

Comment: It might be possible to a add a new partition/filesystem, then moving/linking things there. The easier way is still getting your configuration (`config.xml`) and re-install everything properly.

Comment: It might even be possible to grow the fs through `gpart` and `growfs` ... but re-installing everything properly is still the easiest way.

Comment: It is always not a good option to keep on installing each time I have issues. Better the hard way where the easiest will be always easy.

Comment: In that case, it means anyway downtime. Re-installing is more simple and quicker than doing it the hard way. pfSense is not a full-grown system, the configuration is just 1 file to backup and restore. (Anyway I did the exercice and will post how to grow fs)

Comment: Sure! BTW, currently the network traffic is being routed through MS forefront TMG & I'm testing pfsense in parallel; having few users.

Answer (score 6):

pfSense is currently based on FreeBSD 8.x. The ability to grow a UFS filesystem **live** is only coming with FreeBSD 10.x, so all this should be done from a rescue/install mode.

**First do a backup of your `config.xml` file !**

To grow the pfSense root filesystem you must first properly re-size the BSD partition scheme (aka "bsd slices"):

- **re-size the BSD partition**

  On console mode or through ssh, start a `Shell` (example is only 4GB install with 4GB free disk):

  `[admin]:`**`gpart show`**

  ```
  =>      63  16777153  ad0  MBR  (8.0G)
          63   8388513    1  freebsd  [active]  (4G)
     8388576   8388640       - free -  (4.0G)

  =>      0  8388513  ad0s1  BSD  (4G)
          0       16         - free -  (8.0k)
         16  7339921      1  freebsd-ufs  (3.5G)
    7339937  1048576      2  freebsd-swap  (512M)
  ```

  (assuming your disk is seen as `ad0`)

  `[admin]:`**`gpart resize -i 1 ad0`**

  ```
  ad0s1 resized
  ```

  Due to a bug in `gpart` regarding the old MBR partitioning schemes, we need to force a global size update, as the MBR is still having the old global size.

  Get the `freebsd` real partition size (2nd column of the `gpart show ad0` output):

  `[admin]:`**`gpart show ad0`**

  ```
  =>      63  16777153  ad0  MBR  (8.0G)
          63  16777152    1  freebsd  [active]  (8G)
    16777215         1       - free -  (512B)
  ```

  Using `bsdlabel` to edit this value onto the zise of `c:` line:

  `[admin]:`**`bsdlabel -e /dev/ad0s1`**

  ```
  # /dev/ad0s1:
  8 partitions:
  #          size     offset    fstype   [fsize bsize bps/cpg]
    a:   15728640         16    4.2BSD        0     0     0
    b:    1048496   15728656      swap
    c:    8388513          0    unused        0     0     # "raw" part, don't edit
  ```

  So edit it to match this number; in our example: 16777152 (editor is `vi`):

  ```
  # /dev/ad0s1:
  8 partitions:
  #          size     offset    fstype   [fsize bsize bps/cpg]
    a:   15728640         16    4.2BSD        0     0     0
    b:    1048496   15728656      swap
    c:   16777152          0    unused        0     0     # "raw" part, don't edit`
  ```

  The partitions have now been re-sized properly.
- **Growing pfSense root filesystem**

  As the default disk partioning is setting a swap at the end of the disk, we must first note down its size and remove it before growing the root filesystem:

  (Just be sure it the 2nd filesystem of your `ad0s1` - 3rd column value in `gpart show` output)

  `[admin]:`**`gpart delete -i 2 ad0s1`**

  Re-sizing our root partition to all, but the swap partition size (gpart `-s` option do accept only integer values, so 7.5G = 7680M):

  `[admin]:`**`gpart resize -i 1 -s 7680M ad0s1`**

  ```
  ad0s1a resized
  ```

  `[admin]:`**`growfs /dev/ad0s1a`**

  ```
  We strongly recommend you to make a backup before growing the Filesystem

   Did you backup your data (Yes/No) ? Yes
  new file systemsize is: 3932160 frags
  Warning: 302144 sector(s) cannot be allocated.
  growfs: 7532.5MB (15426496 sectors) block size 16384, fragment size 2048
          using 41 cylinder groups of 183.72MB, 11758 blks, 23552 inodes.
  super-block backups (for fsck -b #) at:
   7525280, 7901536, 8277792, 8654048, 9030304, 9406560, 9782816, 10159072, 10535328, 10911584,
   11287840, 11664096, 12040352, 12416608, 12792864, 13169120, 13545376, 13921632, 14297888,
   14674144, 15050400
  ```

  And re-creating the swap partition:

  `[admin]:`**`gpart add -t freebsd-swap ad0s1`**

  ```
  ad0s1b added
  ```

  Done. Our partition table is now as follow and the root filesystem has been properly expanded to use its full partition:

  `[admin]:`**`gpart show`**

  ```
  =>      63  16777153  ad0  MBR  (8.0G)
          63  16777152    1  freebsd  [active]  (8G)
    16777215         1       - free -  (512B)

  =>       0  16777152  ad0s1  BSD  (8G)
           0        16         - free -  (8.0k)
          16  15728640      1  freebsd-ufs  (7.5G)
    15728656   1048496      2  freebsd-swap  (512M)
  ```

For more information about FreeBSD `gpart` and `growfs` commands:

- [growfs manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=growfs&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD%208.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) (FreeBSD 8.3)
- [gpart manual](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gpart&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD%208.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) (FreeBSD 8.3)

Note: `gpart` bug regarding the old MBR partitioning scheme is still true as of FreeBSD-10.0.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation.. Let me check this & post back soon. :)

Comment: Good answer. Lacking some troubleshooting info. Here is a link that will complete this answer for people getting stuck with "operation not permitted error" https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=93967.10;wap2